# What is polytropic index?

Tags: thermodynamics, terminology, adiabatic

1. What is [polytropic index](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=polytropic+index)?
2. What is the connection between it and work of an adiabatic system?

I tried surfing but didn't able to find a proper answer for that.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by your second sentence. There's no such thing as an "adiabatic system"; there are *adiabatic processes* during which no heat flows into or out of the system. If the system is an ideal gas, then $pV^k =$ constant if the process is also quasi-static (quasi-equilibrium), so this is an example of a polytropic *process*, and $k$ is the polytropic index for that particular process. What in the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytropic_process) was unsatisfactory?

Answer (score 4):

The polytropic index is that defined via a polytropic equation of state of the form $P \propto \rho^{1 +1/n}$, where $P$ is pressure, $\rho$ is density, and $n$ is the polytropic index.

There is a relationship between the polytropic index and the adiabatic index. The latter is defined through
$PV^{\gamma} = $constant. If we consider adiabatic changes then $\gamma$ is the ratio of specific heats.

You can see that in this case $\gamma = 1 + 1/n$, so that $n = 1/(\gamma -1)$.
For an adiabatic change in an ideal monatomic gas $\gamma = 5/3$ and the polytropic index is $n=3/2$.

Unfortunately, whilst the above is the accepted definition of polytropic index in astrophysics, it appears from a brief www trawl that many also appear to refer to $\gamma$ as the polytropic index.

Answer (score 3):

For a polytropic process path, one in which $pV^n$=constant along the path, n is the polytropic index.  Such a process path is typically regarded as reversible, and the temperature, volume, and pressure can be varying along the path. Also, heat exchange between the system and surroundings can be occurring.  A subset of polytropic paths are adiabatic reversible paths in which no heat exchange is occurring between the system and surroundings.  In that case, k is equal to $\gamma$, the ratio of the heat capacity at constant pressure to the heat capacity at constant volume.

Comment: Certainly in astrophysics that is not the definition of the polytropic index.

Comment: @RobJeffries. It looks to be very closely related, based on a cursory reading of the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytrope). I suppose that in astrophysics, the relation doesn't describe a thermodynamic *process* but rather a *relationship* between thermodynamic variables. But the mathematical relationship is essentially the same.

Comment: I have no background in astrophysics, but the context of the OPs question clearly indicated the thermodynamics version.  Maybe you can say a few things about the astrophysics version.

Comment: Yes there appear to be two definitions in common use.